# UPDATED: Angular 6 + Material: Child component with simple and mat-accordion lists is updated seemingly by holding reference to parent array

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material, angular2-changedetection

(UPDATE: Issue exists when child displays simple mat-accordion list and a simple  list. I've juxtaposed both simple `<div>` and accordion lists to show possible change detection effects in simple list and mat-accordion. It seems child is holding reference to parent array of 'things'.)

Angular 6+. Material 6+ Simple code and image below. I've cut this down to as short as possible. ***Also note ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush is active for both child and parent.***

(Stackblitz at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-child-updated)

**SHOWING LIST OF 'THINGS' (Via Child's @Input 'things')**

I'm doing something very simple: showing an array of strings (`things$`) passed to child component (`ChildComponent`) which contains both a simple `<div>` list and a Material `<mat-accordion>` list (for this post's comparison purposes). The data for the lists is passed by the parent (`app.component.ts`) via an `async | pipe` @Input property to the child. The parent obtains the `things$` observable by making a faked 'http' call `fakeHttpGetThings()` which returns a mocked list of 'things' as an observable. **NOTE: Parent redundantly holds an array of things in `this.thingsList`!** All very nice.

**ADDING A 'THING' TO PARENT'S ARRAY LIST BUT CHILD's `<mat-accordion>` IS UPDATED ON CLICK EVENTS ANYWAY...**

As mentioned, the parent is also maintaining an array of 'things' in `this.thingsList` where it is initially assigned via an rxjs `map()` when the parent makes the `fakeHttpGetThings()` to get all 'things'. It is also updated upon `addThing()`. Redundant, but so what. BUT, the parent also wants to ADD a 'thing' to the child lists (incorrectly but it still somewhat works). A faked 'http' `fakeHttpAddThing('new thing')` call is made, which returns the 'thing' to be added. It is redundantly added the parent's `this.thingsList` as well. **NOTE, here the simple `<div>` and `<mat-acccordion>` lists in the Child were never directly manipulated, i.e., there is no dedicated @Input for the new 'thing' to be added to the child. On return of `fakeHttpAddThing()`, within the `subscribe( res ...)`, the new `'thing'` is merely pushed to the `this.thingsList` array IN THE PARENT app.component.ts.**

**Why?:** Does adding to parent array update the child's simple `<div>` and  lists even with ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush which is active all over?

**ISSUE: BUT the simple `<div>` and `<mat-accordion>` lists do get updated when one of the accordion panels is expanded (events are triggered). This happens even though the 'irrelevant' `this.thingsList` in the parent is updated and ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush is active for both parent and child. Why?**

**Summary**

Again, I had passed the original list of things via '@Input set' in `child.component.ts`. But upon add, even though the list array in the child is never directly updated (the @Input set is NOT triggered), the child's simple list and the  list of things shows the new thing added upon panel expansion. Why? I'm stumped. This shouldn't be working IMO. It seems the child is holding a reference to the parent's `this.thingsList` array. Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated. Snippets below:

app.component.ts:

```js
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template:
    `
      <app-child
        [things]="(things$ | async)?.things">
      </app-child>
      <input
        #thingbox>
        <button (click)="addThing(thingbox.value)">add thing</button>
        <button>do nothing</button>
    `,
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  thingsList: any[];
  things$: Observable<{message: string, things: any[]}>;

  constructor() { }

  addThing = (thing: string): void => {
    this.fakeHttpAddThing(thing)
        .pipe(
          map( (res) => {
            return res;
          }),
        )
        .subscribe( (res) => {
          // I KNOW THIS map() ASSIGNMENT IS WRONG AND UNNECCESARY
          // BUT STILL CHANGE DETECTION IS TRIGGERED IN ChildComponent
          // EVERYTHING WORKS FINE IF REMOVED.
          this.thingsList.push(res.thing);
          return res;
        });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.things$ = this.fakeHttpGetThings()
        .pipe(
          map( (thingsResponse): {message: string, things: any[]} => {
            // I KNOW THIS map() ASSIGNMENT IS WRONG AND UNNECCESARY
            // BUT STILL CHANGE DETECTION IS TRIGGERED IN ChildComponent
            // EVERYTHING WORKS FINE IF REMOVED.
            this.thingsList = thingsResponse.things;
            return thingsResponse;
          }),
        );
  }

  fakeHttpGetThings = (): Observable<{message: string, things: any[]}> => {

    const things: any[] = [
      {
        thingKey: 'THING1',
      },
      {
        thingKey: 'THING2',
      },
      {
        thingKey: 'THING3',
      }
    ];

    return of({message: 'SUCCESS', things: things});
  }

  fakeHttpAddThing(thing: string): Observable<{message: string, thing: any}> {

    return of({
      message: 'SUCCESS',
      thing: {thingKey: thing}
    });
  }
}
```

child.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template:
    `
      <div
        *ngFor="let thing of _things">

        {{thing.thingKey}}
      </div>

      <mat-accordion>
        <mat-expansion-panel
          *ngFor="let thing of _things">
          <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            {{thing.thingKey}}
          </mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <p>{{thing.thingKey}} contents</p>
        </mat-expansion-panel>
      </mat-accordion>
    `,
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  _things: any[] = null;

  @Input()
    set things(things) {
      this._things = things;
    }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please create a StackBlitz project instead.

stackblitz.com

Comment: Thanks. Added SB link.

Answer (score 2):

You're not using OnPush change detection so change detection is firing in every component basically every time a user interacts with your app (clicking, hovering, scrolling etc) and that things array is always the same reference being manipulated no matter where you do it.

if you want to use on push change detection then do:

```
import {ChangeDetectionStrategy} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template:
    `
      <div
        *ngFor="let thing of _things">

        {{thing.thingKey}}
      </div>
    `,
   changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

Now change detection won't trigger unless some change detection trigger occurs (input/output events, async pipe events etc)

Comment: how is the child gaining access to the array reference?

Comment: arrays are passed by reference in javascript, all your components / functions are showing / manipulating / passing the same array.

Comment: You're referring to this.thingsList = thingsResponse.things.  The child is using that reference since it's passed implicitly to it by the response async'd Observable.....

Comment: you only ever create one array and pass the reference around.  Any consumer that manipulates that array is manipulating the reference so any consumer holding that reference will see the changes.

Comment: I understand what you're saying...just to be clear, I never pass that array explicitly to the child. It seems, however, I am passing it implicitly...the change detection is hiding the issue. Goes away as soon as I OnPush activate it.

Comment: you do explicitly pass the array to the child at [things]="(things$ | async)?.things", the array coming through the async pipe is the exact same array reference that you save a reference to on your component in the map() function in our onInit hook, and the same reference that you later manipulate in your add thing function. Arrays references are always what is passed, so you are passing it explicitly. Same for objects. Primitives (strings, numbers, booleans) are different, they're passed by value.